# Trying to add a leading "$" to JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please review this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/WuMpz/10/).

What I'm trying to do is add a leading "$" to the results. The label "**in Retained Aid**" works fine, but when I add the "$" to it, it does something with the numbers where instead of showing a running total, it simply adds the digits to the output.

So, adding **2000** + **4000** + **5000**, displays as "**$200040005000 in Retained Aid**" (with the dollar sign, but doesn't actually add the numbers).

```
var updateTotal = function () {
  var input1 = parseInt($('#earnedAid1').val() || 0);
  var input2 = parseInt($('#earnedAid2').val() || 0);
  var input3 = parseInt($('#earnedAid3').val() || 0);        
  $('#total').text("$" + input1 + input2 + input3 +" in Retained Aid");
};
```

**Edit:** In addition to that, just putting a "2" in the input box, displays it as $200 in the output.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match the code you posted above.

Comment: Please stop abusing `<kbd>` tags. They're *not* for adding decoration to random text.

Comment: Sorry. What are they for then? I honestly thought they were just decoration...

Comment: The fiddle above has been updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: They're for making up keyboard keys. If I want to tell you to press ctrl+c, I would use `<kbd>` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding a string `"$"` before doing the sum which making it a string. So, subsequently if you add a number it will string consider it a string.

```
"some string" + 1 + 2 = "some string12" // considers 1,2 as strings while adding to the string.
"some string" + (1+2) = "some string3" //1+2 gets executed & then gets appended to the string

var sum = input1 + input2 + input3;
$('#total').text("$" + sum +" in Retained Aid");
```

Alternative:

```
$('#total').text("$" + (input1 + input2 + input3) +" in Retained Aid");
```

Comment: Not sure why this was hammered with downvotes, unless it was very wrong and rapidly fixed...

Comment: @meagar, it was unformatted code for a few seconds, and that plus the lack of explanations triggered the downvotes I'm afraid. (This is now fixed.)

Comment: `$('#total').text("$" + (input1 + input2 + input3) +" in Retained Aid");` as an alternative

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - that was my bad.. I usually answer, then edit for corrections. I forgot to format. Man, those were some fast downvotes & still getting 'em.

Comment: @Ramunas - absolutely. let me add it too.. separated into 2 lines for clarity.

Comment: @Krishna, yup, fastest gun in the west goes with its own problems :)

Comment: @Krishna, ignore the haters. Your's is the best solution

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the bad code in the beginning. I'll be more careful.

Comment: @meagar I totally downvoted because initially it was a typical FGITW answer. Read crap

Comment: @Krishna, You wouldn't be saying that if you had 7 negative votes. Cheers. By the way, I upvoted you

Comment: @webfrogs All these comments, including the upvote one, are about *this answer*, not your original question.

Comment: Just figured that out and deleted my "Thanks" because of it. Learned what an FGITW is, too... but why is that bad. Are answers that are fast and correct, a good thing to have?

Comment: @webfrogs - this comments section is getting too long. 1 last comment. Fast answers even when they are correct, if they're not formatted correctly & has no explanation next to it will get down voted

Answer (score 3):

Javascript uses the `+` operator to concatenate strings and to add numbers. If it sees only numbers in an expression, it will add them, but as soon as you have strings in the expression, it will treat them all as strings. This explains what you're seeing.

So how to solve it?

Simple: Firstly, make sure the values `input1`, `input2` and `input3` are numeric values, and then add them together in a separate expression from the string parts.

You're already doing the first part of this in your code where you do `parseInt()`, although you do need to add a validity check for `NaN` ('Not A Number') results, or you'll get the text `NaN` in your output.

The second part is simply a case of wrapping the numbers in a set of brackets so they're treated as a separate expression:

```
$('#total').text("$" + (input1 + input2 + input3) +" in Retained Aid");
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` is the operator for text concatenation in JS as well – so once you start with a text value and “add” stuff to it, the following values will be converted to text as well, and since no mathematical addition takes place any more, but it’s all just string concatenation from there on.

But you can simply fix that, by using parenthesis to group what part of the expression should be executed first:

```
$('#total').text("$"+(input1 + input2 + input3) +" in Retained Aid");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WuMpz/9/